# Google Cloud Aritfact Registry cannot pull the image using the latest tag

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

We have a new repo made in another service project. northamerica-northwest1-docker.pkg.dev/service-project/app-name-image:111111

The tag id we have is generated by gitlab-ci.

We build and push successfully and we are able to docker pull the specific tag but when using :latest, it cannot says "failed to fetch "latest".

One of our older repos can pull "latest" but this new repo cannot. I have tried using the same image name convention but still does not work.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does the image has the `latest` tag?

Comment: it does not have the latest tag. How would you go about tagging it the latest along with the latest number?

Answer (score 0):

I have tagged id and also latest and pushed both at the same pipeline.